# Finding the lenght of a parameterized curve 2

Tags: integration, curves, parametrization

I have a curve C, which is the intersection between the plane

$$
3z = xy   
$$
and the cylinder
$$
x^2 = 2y
$$
I come to the conclusion that i can parameterize it by
$$
x = t
$$
$$
y = t^2/2
$$
$$
z = t^3/6
$$
which, finally, gives me this integral to get the lenght of the curve between the origin and the point (6,18,36):
$$
\int_{0}^{6} \sqrt{1+ t + t^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}t 
$$
But then I am lost... I am not sure if it is my parametrization which is not done right (or in the easiest way), or I am just not seeing an easy way to integrate this. An hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: complete the square

Comment: $3z = xy$ is a plane?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Completing the square doesn't help at all

Answer (score 1):

Frequently, when simplifying integrals containing quadratic expressions, a useful substitution is to define a variable equal to the derivative of the quadratic expression.

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(1-t+\frac{t^2}{2}\right)=t-1$$

so let $s=t-1$

Then

$$ \int_0^6\sqrt{1-t+\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_1^7\sqrt{s^2+1}\,ds$$

To complete the integral you will need the trigonometric substitution $s=\tan\theta$ and will need to use the integral of $\sec^3\theta$. By this point you should be familiar with both of these.